# Best (and correct) use of nmap to scan own computer?

Tags: security, localhost, nmap

Which is the most correct way to give Nmap my own computer as a target? Example commands:

```
nmap -T5 -A -v localhost
nmap -T5 -A -v 192.168.0.7
nmap -T5 -A -v (my external ip address)
```

Can you explain what's the difference in calling one or the other of those?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not skilled in this but in my opinion you would want to test from a different computer. Two cases: one that is on the same network as you, one that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those would be which interface nmap tries to connect to. If you use localhost, nmap will attempt to establish connections to any application listening on your local computer using a virtual loopback network device. This means that the OS will process the connections, but your network card will likely not be involved.

If you use 192.168.0.7 (I assume this is the address assigned to your ethernet or wifi card), it will attempt to connect to any application listening on your local computer, but (depending on how smart your OS and networking drivers are), it may actually go through your network card, and maybe even out to the first switch that you are connected to and then back. The connections will not be routed on the internet, so your router will not be involved.

Finally, if you use the public IP address of your router, the connections will go through your network card, to your router, and then through any port forwarding or routing rules configured in your router. This may or may not route the connection back to your computer, depending on which rules are set up and the firewall on the router.

Note that for the first two invocations, it is possible for application listening for connections locally to listen on either one or both of the interfaces (loopback or network card), so it is possible for applications to be listening only on the loopback device and not the network interface and vise versa. So they could return different results. However, anyone outside your computer would not be able to establish a connection to anything listening on only the loopback interface. However, experience tells me that most applications listening for connections tend to listen on all available interfaces, so there is not likely to be a difference in the result of the first two invocations.